# What is the time dependence in the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

The general solution of the Schrodinger is $\Psi(x,t)$.
Is it correct to interpret it as $(\Psi(x))(t)$ namely, the field $\Psi(x)$ is the actual state of the particle and $(\Psi(x))(t)$ is a function that gives the state of the particle at every instant?

**Example**:
If we evaluate $\Psi(x,t)$ at a certain istant of time, for example at $t=0$, we have:
$$\Psi(x,0)\equiv \Psi_0(x)$$
I think that $\Psi_0(x)$ can be interpreted as a state that is not stationary. In other words, at $t=0$ the particle state is $\Psi_0(x)$ and then it change smoothly to another one.

**Another example**: Consider $\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)e^{iEt/\hbar}$ where $\psi(x)$ is such that  $\hat H \psi(x)=E \psi(x)$.

$\Psi(x,0)=\psi(x)$ is the state at instant $t=0$

$\Psi(x,t_o)=\psi(x)exp(iEt/\hbar)$ is the state at instant $t=t_0$

However, since this states differs just by a phase factor they have the same values for all the observable quantities. For this reason it's like these states are all equivalent to  $\psi(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the solutions $\psi(x,t)$ to the time-dependent Schrödinger equation should be viewed as functions $t\mapsto \psi_t(x)$ that assign to every time $t$ a state (= Hilbert space vector) $\psi_t(x)$. More generically we write $\lvert \psi(t)\rangle$ for such time-dependent states without specializing to the position representation.

There are now two things you can mean by "stationary state": You can mean an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian with $H\lvert \psi\rangle = E\lvert \psi\rangle$ for some number $E$, or you can mean the solution to the Schrödinger equation that results from using $\lvert \psi(0)\rangle = \lvert \psi\rangle$ as the initial condition: $\lvert \psi(t)\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Et}\lvert \psi(0)\rangle$. At every instant $t_0$, we have that $\lvert \psi(t_0)\rangle$ differs from $\lvert \psi(0)\rangle$ only by a phase $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Et_0}$ and hence $\lvert \psi(t_0)\rangle$ is the same state as $\lvert \psi(0)\rangle$ for all $t_0$ since states are actually *rays* in Hilbert space and an overall phase does not change the physical state a vector represents - this is the reason such $\lvert \psi(t)\rangle$ are "stationary": The actual state does not change with time.